# Incorrect compiler error usage of uninitialized variable

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I just encountered a case where Visual Studio tells me my code might result in accessing an uninitialized variable, but the rules of boolean logic dictate this isn't possible here.

I simplified the code to visualize the problem, in this case appearing for `x`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDictionary<String, MyType> dictionary = null;
    if (new Random().Next() % 2 == 0)
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyType>();
        dictionary.Add("xyz", MyType.Whatever);
        dictionary.Add("abc", MyType.DontCare);
    }

    var myType = dictionary?.TryGetValue("abc", out var x) ?? false ? x : MyType.None;
}

enum MyType
{
    None,
    Whatever,
    DontCare
}
```

In case `dictionary` isn't initialized it's null, thus resulting in `??` evaluating the ternary operator to `false`. This is the only case where `x` won't be initialized, but still I get the error message for `x` in the true case of the ternary operator.

Remarks: Setting parenthesis doesn't change anything, and resolving the ternary operator to a full-fledged if doesn't either.

Is this a known behavior or a bug?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I DO know how to fix the problem. I was just slightly surprised to encounter this error, since the described problem, accessing the uninitialized `x`, will never happen according to boolean logic.

EDIT: Using a full if doesn't change the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    MyType myType;
    if (dictionary?.TryGetValue("abc", out var x) ?? false)
    {
        myType = x; // <-- error still occurs here
    }
    else
    {
        myType = MyType.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever I've asked myself, if something is a compiler bug, the answer was **no**.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is having a hard time inferring the type of `x`, and error is manifesting in a strange way. Operator precedence for `??` is also worth exploring.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn No, it just doesn't know `x` is never accessed after the `??`.

Comment: I may also have to do with the typing for ternary, where the compiler needs to be sure of a value for x to know how to infer the type of that expression (I did read where you tried with full `if()` code... showing that version, too, might help us).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/916) looks very relevant here. There's a useful link to the spec on [definite assignment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/variables.md#definite-assignment) in there, too, which is what this is all about.

Comment: @KirkLarkin It is. It supports what my answer says: the compiler doesn't know that because it was never built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `x` in this line:

```
var myType = dictionary?.TryGetValue("abc", out var x) ?? false ? x : MyType.None;
```

Since you have a null-propagation operator (`?.`), `x` will never be assigned when `dictionary` is `null`. You have to take out `x` as a separate variable above the `var` with a default value.

```
MyType x = MyType.None;

var myType = dictionary?.TryGetValue("abc", out x) ?? false ? x : MyType.None;
```

The static compiler just isn't smart enough to figure out the null-propagation operator will cause that expression always to return false (and hence `x` is never used). Not it just treats the statement as if it can.

As you can see on the C# language Github page, there is an [active feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/916) to let the compiler figure out the outcome of the null-propagation operator.

Comment: I do realize the problem, my point is, that the true case of the ternary operator will never occur when x is unassigned

Comment: The static compiler doesn't know that. It doesn't know the result of the part before `??` on beforehand. It doesn't know the `true` expression is never called.

Comment: until now Roslyn has always be able to check all code paths, that's why I'm surprised this isn't the case here

Comment: regarding your last edit: that's just wrong. the if evaluates false, thus not accessing `x`

Comment: The static compiler doesn't know that! @FlorianKoch

Comment: Yeah, and that's the core of my question: The static compiler was (for me) until now always able to evaluate all code paths based on boolean logic - why isn't that the case here? it's not the case that it can't be evaluated statically, because the behavior does not depend on any runtime element